# viewing the variable stored in an C array

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I am making a code that reads the data every time a new frequency is applied.
(I have a list of frequencies in an array)
I would like to display at the start of the set of readings a text saying **current frequency (Hz):**  and then the value defined in the following array `int freq[] = {1000 , 10000 , 30000 }` . I am indexing the different frequencies in a for loop with the following code

```
for (byte count = 0; count < 6; count = count + 1) {
    Serial.print("current Frequency(hz): ");
    Serial.println(  freq[count], 4);
```

However when I open the serial monitor I get numbers that I have not defined as a in the freq array. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: What have you read about these operators in your favorite C teaching resource?

Comment: Break it down into individual steps.  They even included parentheses for you so you don't need to be too familiar with operator precedence.

Comment: Michael Adlerstein, What type is `cmd`?  Code better as `((cmd & 0x0Fu) << 10) | (data & 0x03FF)`  (add u)

Comment: Note that the mask for `data` isolates its 10 least significant bits. The 4 bits of `cmd` are shifted left by 10 bits. So the `cmd`  ends up at bits 10..13 of `data_word`.

Answer (score 2):

It takes the 4 least significant bits of `cmd` and the 10 least significant bits of `data` and combines them as follows:

```
cmd                       data
+---+---+---+---+---+     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
... |   |   |   |   |     ... |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
      |   |   |   |             |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
      |   |   |   +---------+   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
      |   |   +---------+   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
      |   +---------+   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
      +---------+   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
                |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
                v   v   v   v   v   v   v   v   v   v   v   v   v   v
      +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
      | 0 | 0 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
      +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
      data_word
```